# How to read mass from a Lagrangian if two fields are coupled?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, mass, field-theory

This question comes from [problem 83.6 in Srednicki's textbook "Quantum Field Theory"](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html). Part a) of the problem asks us to consider the case of three light quark flavors, with masses $m_{u}, m_{d}$ and $m_{s}$. We must find the mass-squared of the eight pseudo-goldstone bosons.

The answer is that after some calculations, the mass terms in the chiral Lagrangian are: 
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{mass} = -2v^{3}f_{\pi}^{-2} [(m_{u}+m_{d})\pi^{+}\pi^{-} + (m_{u}+m_{s})K^{+}K^{-} + (m_{d}+m_{s})\overline{K}^{0}K^{0} + \frac{1}{2}m_{u}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\eta + \pi^{0})^{2} + \frac{1}{2}m_{d}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\eta - \pi^{0})^{2} + \frac{2}{3}m_{s}\eta^{2}
\end{equation}
Thus, 
\begin{align}
m_{\pi^{\pm}}^{2} &= 2v^{3}f_{\pi}^{-2} (m_{u}+m_{d})\\
m_{K^{\pm}}^{2} &= 2v^{3}f_{\pi}^{-2} (m_{u}+m_{s})\\
m_{K^{0},\overline{K}^{0}}^{2} &= 2v^{3}f_{\pi}^{-2} (m_{d}+m_{s})\\
m_{\pi^{0},\eta}^{2} &= \frac{4}{3}v^{3}f_{\pi}^{-2} [m_{u}+ m_{d}+ m_{s} \pm (m_{u}^{2} + m_{d}^{2} + m_{s}^{2} - m_{u}m_{d}- m_{d}m_{s}- m_{s}m_{u})^{1/2}]
\end{align}
My question is: whilst it is easy to read $m_{\pi^{\pm}}^{2}, m_{K^{\pm}}^{2}$ and $m_{K^{0},\overline{K}^{0}}^{2}$ from the expression of $\mathcal{L}_{mass}$, how can I derive $m_{\pi^{0},\eta}^{2}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write the mass terms in a matrix form and diagaonlize. E.g. for the case of real scalars,
$$
V_{mass} = \frac12 m_{ij} \phi_i \phi_j
$$
where $m_{ij} = \left.\partial V / \partial \phi_i \partial \phi_j\right|_{\phi = 0}$. This contains the off-diagonal elements that mix interaction eigenstates. By diagonalizing the symmetric matrix $m_{ij}$ with a unitary matrix, we find the mass eigenvalues,
$$
m^\text{diag} = U^T m U
$$
where $U^T U = 1$, and mass eigenestates $\hat\phi = U\phi$. We can rewrite the Lagrangian in mass eigenstates, e.g.
$$
V_{mass} = \frac12 m_{ij} \phi_i \phi_j = \frac12 m^\text{diag}_{ij} \hat\phi_i \hat\phi_j
$$ 
Written in this mass eigenbasis, we can again read off the masses and there are no mixing terms as we diagaonlized the mass matrix.